# ESP8266 ESP-07 does not respond to commands

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I just bought an ESP8266 ESP-07 V1.0 Serial Wifi Transceiver. Similiar to this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP8266-Serial-Wifi-Transceiver-Module-for-Arduino-ESP-07-V1-0-New-/331868488091

I have connect the RX and TX pins to the RX and TX pin of the Arduino (RX to TX and TX to RX), VCC is connected to 3.3V and GND is connected to Arduino ground.
I have used the following code and writing commands to the module using the serial monitor:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int RX_PIN = 3;
int TX_PIN = 4;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(115200);

    while (!Serial){
    ;
  }

    while (!mySerial){
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Ready");
}
void loop()
{
    // listen for communication from the ESP8266 and then write it to the serial monitor
    if ( mySerial.available() )   {  Serial.write( mySerial.read() );  }

    // listen for user input and send it to the ESP8266
    if ( Serial.available() )       {  mySerial.write( Serial.read() );  }
}
```

Whatever I type (for example AT+GMR) in the serial monitor at 9600 baud I don't get any response. What could be the reason? Both NL and CR is added to the command.

When pressing reset on the ESP-module I get this in the Serial monitoring:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: pin 1 is TX of hardware Serial. and the esp8266 should be on SoftwareSerial RX/TX pins, not on RX/TX labeled pins

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for your reply. I have now updated the code. But still no luck :-/

Comment: and the wiring?

Comment: @Juraj  Arduino RX (pin 3) => ESP TX, Arduino TX (pin 4) => ESP RX, Arduino 3.3V => ESP VCC, Arduino GND => ESP GND

Comment: you changed the baud rate. the AT firmware's default is 115200 baud, but SoftwareSerial can't receive reliably at 115200

Comment: @Juraj Is there anyway to fix that then?

Comment: the output after reset is bootlog at different baud rate. did you try to send AT after "Ready"?

Comment: @Juraj Yes, if I do that I don't get any response. But reading around I see I might need to put a resistor between the TX from Arduino (pin 4) to ESP8266 RX pin since it operates at 3V not 5V? Which means the ESP8266 RX pin might be broken? 100 ohm resistor should be enough if I have calculated correctly.

Comment: the esp8266 has no pronlem with  5 V Serial

Comment: set the baud rates to 74800 to see the boot log

Comment: @Juraj Sweet, that gave me "ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)". Is it only boot log that works at 74880?

Comment: yes only boot log. is it possible that the esp8266 is without AT firmware? even with SoftwareSerial at 115200 you should see "ready" from AT firmware and get some response to AT commands

Comment: @Juraj I have asked the seller about the firmware since the information does not say anything about it. As far as I can see there is no way for me to install/update the firmware using the Arduino Uno.

Comment: why not? it is simple. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=634684.0

Comment: @Juraj This is totally new to me. But I tried it out now. Downloaded NodeMCU and wired it up. But get the following when clicking on "flash"Note:Serial port connected.
Note:Begin find ESP8266.
Note:ESP8266 ACK success.
Error:Read ESP8266 register timeout.

Comment: NodeMcu? there is nothing about nodemcu in that link. did you set the switch to flashing mode and reset?

Comment: @Juraj Got it working now. But a little bit unsure which files I actually need to upload/update. I have used esp_init_data_default_v05.bin and blank.bin

Comment: For anyone still confused (like I was), the code should still say `Serial.begin(115200)` but the Arduino log monitor should be set to 74880 baud.

Comment: @Juraj Got it working now thanks to the forum link. So I will accept it as answer if you make one :)

Comment: with AT firmware 1.7 you can use my WiFiEspAT library in UNO. the library is in library manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The esp8266 is without AT firmware. Even with SoftwareSerial at 115200 baud you should see "ready" from AT firmware and get some response to AT commands.

This esp8266 module adapter is simple to flash. It makes the 5 V to 3.3 V conversion for power and RX pin and has a program switch (io 0) and a reset button to put the esp8266 into flashing mode.

Use an USB-to-TTL-Serial adapter or an Arduino with USB chip to connect the adapter to PC. Then switch to "program" and reset it and it will be in flashing mode.

You can download the AT firmware [here](https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at). I recommend ESP8266 NonOS AT Bin V1.7.1. Don't try 2.0, it is very different (ESP32 AT firmware build for esp8266).

To flash it, use [esptool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool#installation--dependencies)

The command to flash the AT firmware binaries to any module with at least 1 MB flash memory is:

```
esptool.py write_flash --flash_size 2MB-c1 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/1024+1024/user1.2048.new.5.bin 0x1fb000 blank.bin 0x1fc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x1fe000 blank.bin
```

don't wonder about the 2MB-c1 setting and don't change it. The AT binaries are build for 2MB-c1 partitioning. On 1 MB flash it will not support AT firmware OTA update.

If you want to use the [Espressif Flash Download Tool](https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14), use the same settings as on esptool command line.